# How do I print a list in Python while sorting it alphabetically?

Tags: python, list

I seem to not be able to print all the lines alphabetically from the file named abcd.txt

```
abcd = open("abcd.txt", "r")
lines = abcd.readlines()
lines.sort()
print(abcd.read())
```

It doesn't sort the letters in the file alphabetically, and the shell just shows a blank line whenever I run it.
The text file accompanying it is as follows:

a

irfe

fr

b

tt

bgt

eb

gef

df

fw

fre

r

g

er

bgt

eg

rt

g

ge

e

q

e

et

i

uklumh

ngdf

gdv

s

How would I print these lines? And can you see any reasons why it isn't sorting the file?

Comment: This code wouldn't give that output. Nevertheless, it should be obvious that you've sorted the `lines` list, not the file itself; if you read the file again, you'll get the original order.

Comment: I don't know Python but you seem to be printing the wrong variable. Maybe `print(lines)` will work?

Comment: That worked, thanks @Antti29

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting lines, not file. So check & use sorted lines:

```
abcd = open("abcd.txt", "r")
lines = abcd.readlines()
lines.sort()
print('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly